# How to create a grid on top of an image, so that each singular grid box can cover each pixel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel, pixel-art, pixel-grid

Okay, so I've been trying to create a grid, but so far I can't seem to get it right.
Basically, I want a grid, that covers each pixel in an image. Like, each pixel has a black outline, sort of. So far, I've come up with this, by creating a pattern. But, as you can see, the individual pixels aren't outlined, but a big box essentially covers tons of pixels.

[image]

However, what I actually want, is this effect, as you can see below. I can't seem to get it right.

[image]

Right now, I'm using the Channels layer section in PhotoShop to do this, as that's something I found that worked in a tutorial.

Here is another example of what I need

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's simply not possible to draw a grid for every pixel... because if you draw *anything* it **must** be at least 1 pixel in size.

Answer (score 2):

A pixel is the smallest "thing" in a bitmap software like Photoshop is. So, if you want something visible, like the black grid, it can't be between pixel, because there is nothing else than well ... pixels ^^.
So what you need is a pixel, and around, a black line, that are black pixels in fact.

The pattern is a good solution imo, you need to create a 2px by 2px file, and blacken the pixels as shown here, and use it as pattern in edit.

[image]

Then you use the pattern tool and you will have a grid around